# missing values are not counted in Factor

Tags: r

In my dataset, i have a **field**  with type **factor**.

on `str(age)` i will get:

```
$ age: Factor w/ 75 levels " NA","17","18",..: 25 36 24 39 13 23 35 38 16 28
```

This field contains some `NA`, and i try to count them with:

```
 sum(is.na(as.numeric(unlist(adult[1]))))))
```

but **it always gives me 0, but i know there are some missed values**
With

using `as.numeric(unlist())` i tried to convert factor to num, but it also did not work.

Comment: looks like they might be the string `"NA"` rather than missing NA. For example, `x = factor(c(1:5, "NA"))`. So you can replace this with actual missing `x[x=="NA"] <- NA`, and then drop the `"NA"` levels `x = droplevels(x)`

Comment: or even more perniciously, `" NA"`

Comment: Maybe, because it was first `?` in dataset, and i used openrefine to replace the `?` with `value.replace("?","NA")`

Comment: on Matt suggestion it may be worth chucking a `trimws` in there

Comment: @user20650 how can clean my dataset properly with replacing `NA` as string to real `NA` using **Openrefine**

Comment: @KamyarParastesh ; sorry can't help, never heard of openrefine. But when reading your data in, say using `read.table`, you can set the the `na.strings` argument to set `?` to missing.